# How can I retrieve multiple values from nested XML elements using XDocument.Descendants in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

c# - xDocument.Descendants - Select

hello world!
This is my xml:

```
<DatiBeniServizi>
            <DettaglioLinee>
                <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
                <Descrizione>Ns. Ordine 23-OV107270 del 03/05/23</Descrizione>
                <Quantita>0.00</Quantita>
                <PrezzoUnitario>0.00</PrezzoUnitario>
                <PrezzoTotale>0.00</PrezzoTotale>
                <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
            </DettaglioLinee>
            <DettaglioLinee>
                <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
                <CodiceArticolo>
                    <CodiceTipo>ART</CodiceTipo>
                    <CodiceValore>8014211143410</CodiceValore>
                </CodiceArticolo>
                <CodiceArticolo>
                    <CodiceTipo>EAN</CodiceTipo>
                    <CodiceValore>14341</CodiceValore>
                </CodiceArticolo>
           </DettaglioLinee>
</DatiBeniServizi>
```

and this is my code:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"c:\ft\" + item.ToString());
                var results = xDocument.Descendants("DettaglioLinee").Select(x => new
                {
                   CodiceArt = (string)x.Elements("CodiceArticolo").Elements("CodiceValore").FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToUpper(),
                    Descrizione = (string)x.Elements("Descrizione").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
               }).ToList();
```

with this code i can read the item code "8014211143410" since it is the first result. I would also like to get the EAN code if present but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to how you get the value from `CodiceArticolo/CodiceValore`.

In this case, you shouldn't use `.FirstOrDefault()` to return the array value.

```cs
var results = xDocument.Descendants("DettaglioLinee").Select(x => new
    {
        CodiceArt = (string)x.Elements("CodiceArticolo").Elements("CodiceValore").FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToUpper(),
        Descrizione = (string)x.Elements("Descrizione").FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
        CodiceTipos = x.Elements("CodiceArticolo")?
            .Elements("CodiceTipo")
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKICr0)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer, but what if I wanted to search for a descendant based on the value of the TypeCode instead of reading everything and putting it in a list? Is there any way to read a descendant based on the value of the parent element?

Comment: For example, if you want to just return "EAN" value for `CodiceTipos` property, you can filter with `.Where()`: `x.Elements("CodiceArticolo")?.Elements("CodiceTipo").Select(x => x.Value).Where(x => x == "EAN").ToList()`. Is this something you want? Or you may need to update/create another question to specify what is your desired data.